# How to use "ng-if" within the Html <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a newbie to AngularJS. I am creating an example program.
In that I have an HTML  tag which has to be used based on a condition.

If i apply "ng-if" to the  tag the content under the tag is hidden.

In my scenario the content has to be displayed but, if only the condition satisfies  tag has to be applied.

```
<a href="someurl" ng-if="a != 3>
    <div> Text and image goes here </div>
</a>
```

If "**a**" is not equal to "**3**" then the content has to be displayed without href.

I would need some help to achieve this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yayadanuho/1/edit?html,console,output)**

You can use `ng-attr-href` to achieve that functionality:

```
  <a ng-attr-href="{{(a==3) ? 'someurl' : undefined}}">
     <div> Text and image goes here </div>
  </a>
```

In this condition:

```
{{(a==3) ? 'someurl' : undefined}}
```

`undefined` will completely remove the href attribte.